# Preserve leading zeros when mapping NUMERIC(5,0) to string

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Hopefully this is an easy question. I have a legacy DB2 database on an AS/400 where fields like Zip Code are stored as NUMERIC. When mapping them in NHibernate they are treated as integers and the leading zeros are lost. Typically I would use

`SELECT DIGITS(field) FROM TABLE`

to preserve leading zeros but its my understanding that if I go creating formulas to correct formatting I force the field to become read only.

What is the correct way to map the NUMERIC type (with its leading digits) to a string type and back again?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to deal with it at the wrong level.

Leading zeroes are a display concern; just use `"00000"` as your format string.

Comment: I would tend to disagree that it’s a display concern. The source system makes liberal use of the numeric data type to represent numeric string data, Zip Code is but one example of a myriad of cases where this has been done. Changing the source system to be more accommodating to this project is out of the question; anyone who works in IT understands the political and monetary reasons for this.

Comment: Representing numeric strings as the strings that they are is a domain concern. You would not fix a source system data translation issue 100 times in 100 views, you’d fix it once in the domain. Making it a display concern is also impractical because at the view level values like Zip Code are alpha numeric because of the inclusion of Canadian and UK postal codes at the service layer. Additionally, web service calls have no display concern and no format string. Seeing translation logic like this is the display or service layer is a code smell.

Comment: @tlum: you got a point there. But the problem is, your DB should match your domain, and that's not the case. Also, in a well-engineered app you'd have the format for ZipCodes in a single place, not scattered all over the views.

Answer (score 0):

Diego is right, but if you really need to represent the zip codes as strings in your domain you could implement your own IUserType and use it in your mappings.  However, I'm not sure that you'll be able to handle getting the leading zeroes into the numeric database column (if this is something you need).  I think it would be easy enough if you stored your zip code as '392' in the database and then presented it as '00392' though.

For a quick overiew of what's involved in creating an IUserType take a look at this blog post: [Mapping Strings to Booleans using NHibernate's IUserType](http://lostechies.com/rayhouston/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype/)

Comment: You don't need a IUserType for that. Just a property that does the `ToString("00000")` in `get` and `Convert.ToInt32(value)` on `set`

Comment: Fair enough, but wouldn't that require you to map the property to the database as a string (or define two properties)?